# Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context (error info below)

Tags: php

Finding my feet with this but i got above error which redirected me to line with the below info.

```
if(empty($displayData->sa_params->get('slab_enable'));
```

i'll appreciate some guidance.

thanks!

Comment: Some guidance is here http://php.net/empty

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP with a version < 5.5.0, you cannot check a functions return value directly with [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

> Note:
>
> Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work: empty(trim($name)). Instead, use trim($name) == false.

You have to assign it to a variable first. Further, you are missing a `)`.

Try:

```
$slab_enabled = $displayData->sa_params->get('slab_enable');
if(empty($slab_enabled)) { /*do stuff*/ };
```

If you do not know, which version you use, you can check with [`echo phpversion();`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.phpversion.php)

Answer (score 0):

In some PHP versions, or configurations of servers, passing function to `empty()` causes that error. In that cases best practice is to assign value returned from function to variable and then check if that variable is empty.

Here's an example:

```
$slab_enable = $displayData->sa_params->get('slab_enable'); //assign to variable
if(empty($slab_enable)) //checking if variable is empty
{
   ...
}
```